# Float16 mixed precision being slower than regular float32, keras, tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, automatic-mixed-precision

I am using Tensorflow 2.10 in windows with a NVIDIA RTX 2060 SUPER (with tensor cores) for deep learning. But when enabling mixed precision of float16 the time per epoch actually becomes slower than faster.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

(train_x, train_y), (test_x, test_y) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data()

tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy("mixed_float16")

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : x / 255, input_shape=(32,32,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(4,4)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4096, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation("softmax", dtype="float32")
    ])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"])

print("compute dtype of first layer: ", model.layers[0].compute_dtype)

model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=1020)

model.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
```

I put some images of the problem:
[Here's an image of without using mixed precision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjekb.png)
,
[And here's an image using mixed precision, more slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuSu1.png)

Running the code in Google Colab that uses a more modern version of tensorflow (TF 2.15) does work well, and is faster with mixed precision than without it (as it should be). Here's the link to the colab: [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nPmqHCC3ZVKsQRyhm6E8qpPchA0_2frp?usp=sharing)

I'm not an expert using tensorflow and I have been trying to fix this error for weeks, some help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Other Information:**

I'm using cuDNN version 8.1.1 and Cuda 11.2, that are technically the compatible versions.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Your logs are simple text, you may put that in the question body explicitly.

Comment: You're sure you are hitting the GPU?  Because 16-bit floats are quite painful in the CPU.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, because I previously downgraded Tensorflow from 2.15 to 2.10 (Because TF 2.15 doesn't have GPU support in plain Windows) and I could see a nice difference in speed, also in the images you can see that TF allocates memory to the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is switch to Ubuntu (Linux) and update to the newer Tensorflow 2.15.

In this version mixed precision (float16) is twice of fast compared to the classic float32.

I also upgrade from Cuda 11.2 to 12.2 and from Cudnn 8.1.1 to 8.9

Comment: Are you using the exact same python version along with Cuda+Cudnn?
If so, this probably means the scheduler in the operating system was the only difference.

Comment: @Medoalmasry No, I also switched to Cuda 12.2 and Cudnn 8.9. I think the problem was that Tensorflow 2.10 in windows didn't supported correctly mixed precision.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is the essence of the problem here.
By definition, mixed precision accelerates the learning process by using both 16-bit and 32-bit floating-point types. This is because matrix multiplications and convolutions are quite computationally expensive in 32-bits. However, performing the same calculations in 16-bits heavily reduces the bandwidth required to process the aforementioned computations. Subsequently, this entails more data being processed per epoch. Thus, less time.

Theoretically, you ought to be able to achieve the same accuracy by training the model in mixed precisions. This is because the final loss calculations are calculated in 32-bits. Subsequently, this preserves the model's ability to learn effectively.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, the mixed precision does indeed achieve the same accuracy of using float32, but it takes more time, which does not make sense as you said theoretically.

Comment: @SpaceProgrammer Have you considered the fact that mixed precision is calculated using the tensor cores and not the cuda cores. Additionally, the RTX 2060 SUPER has 2176 cuda cores and only 272 tensor cores. So a lot less bandwidth for mixed precision.

Comment: Yes, I already knew it and thanks for answering. And part of the problem is knowing if Tensorflow is using the tensor cores or the cuda cores. Also in the Google Colab that I shared that uses a T4 gpu that also have less tensor cores than cuda cores, somehow it works faster.